# How does scope work in recursive function when inside a Python class?

Tags: python, recursion, scope

I don't understand why the behavior between `func_1` and `func_2` are different. Intuitively, I thought both shouldn't work, because `memory` is initialized each time when the function is called. But apparently there is more to that. And this trick only works for mutable variables (as the list in `func_1`). What is going on under the hood here?

```
class RecursiveDemo:
    def func_1(self, memory=[]):
        memory.append("@")
        if len(memory) <= 5:
            self.func_1()
        else:
            print("=== Done ===")

    def func_2(self, memory=0):
        memory += 1
        if memory <= 5:
            self.func_2()
        else:
            print("=== Done ===")

r = RecursiveDemo()
r.func_1() ## Works. Done is printed. 
r.func_2() ## Doesn't work. RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: Nothing to do with scope :) The default is not defined "per call" but per function definition and changes to it are reflected over funciton call as you "add" to it. Better do `def func_1(self, memory = None): memory = memory or []` to supply a default empty list or a filled one. so your default [] stacks its values over function calls - the integer is always initted to 0 on call if not given so it never reaches 5 hence the recursion error

Comment: As you can see from the dupe - its a more common "astonishing" thing ppl encounter when delving into python

Comment: Thanks! I tried to google it but I'd never be able to find that dupe link